What does resolution mean in the context of Gabor limit or in context of windowing?
I am trying to understand why there is a tradeoff between sidelobes and main lobe width. This answer explains really well but I don't understand what resolution in time domain means.
From my understanding, because of Gabor's limit, narrow resolution in time domain -> wide resolution in frequency domain and wide resolution in time domain -> narrow resolution in frequency domain. From this, the rectangular window should give the narrowest width in frequency domain, right? Since it has widest resolution (no point is different from other point).
But if we take a window that is raised at edges and lowered in the middle, it has narrower width than rectangular window (from this answer). But wouldn't this have lower resolution than the rectangular since there are points (at the edges) which are more distinguishable (for lack of better term) than the rest?
So, my understanding of resolution/narrowness, especially in understanding the Gabor limit, is inaccurate. Can someone please explain what these mean in the context of windowing?

Time domain resolution refers to how accurately you can determine where a signal of interest occurs in time. The DFT has no time localization over the window you compute it for (see this answer), but if you shorten the DFT window (i.e. take a fewer point DFT) you will improve your time resolution, at the tradeoff of worse frequency resolution.

From my understanding, because of Gabor's limit, narrow resolution in time domain -> wide resolution in frequency domain and wide resolution in time domain -> narrow resolution in frequency domain.

That is correct.

From this, the rectangular window should give the narrowest width in frequency domain, right? Since it has widest resolution (no point is different from other point).

While I said this in my other post, I was kind of implicitly assuming that we wouldn't be considering cases like 1-Hanning windows, as typically the sidelobe gain is pretty poor for the little mainlobe width improvement you get. I don't know if this a correct view or not, but by doing something like a 1-Hanning window, in my opinion you are increasing the uncertainty of where in the window the signal is (i.e. is it at the beginning or the end?). The more you move towards something like a hanning window, the less uncertain you become about where it is in time. Additionally, you have to remember that windowing in the time domain means convolving with a sinc function in the frequency domain. In the case of the 1-Hanning window, more high frequency content is necessary due to the sharp transitions at the edge of the window, requiring higher sidelobes that produces a narrower mainlobe.
This leads to an interesting discussion on resolution for spectral estimators in general. For classical Fourier methods the bias-variance tradeoff becomes a resolution-variance tradeoff. However, this is not the case for modern spectral estimators. Often times, although modern spectral estimators (such as Capon) have slightly worse bias than unmodified periodograms, they often still have better resolution (see this answer). This is due to their statistical accuracy being significantly better, resulting in a better overall spectral estimate since they don't have to sacrifice as much data length to achieve better statistical accuracy (see [1]). This was the point of the edit on the first post you reference. With classical Fourier methods (Periodogram, Correlogram, Bartlett's, Welch's, Blackman-Tukey, etc), you are bound by the resolution-variance tradeoff that the non-adaptive matched filterbank provides. If you use a different filterbank, there are better statistical characteristics that can be achieved, resulting in beating the Rayleigh limit.
[1] Stoica, P., & Moses, R. L. (2005). Spectral analysis of signals (Vol. 452, pp. 25-26). Upper Saddle River, NJ: Pearson Prentice Hall.

Thanks for the clarification
